# WDS ERROR on some workstations (Error retrieving network information (0x80072743))

Tags: dhcp, wds

At first I apologize for my poor English.
I've installed WDS role on a Windows Server 2008 R2 and configured it with an install WIM Image of Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and its associated boot image and unattended answer file. 
My WDS server is a standalone server and the DHCP server is a cisco catalyst 3750 switch located on a different subnet. I use ip-helpers command to forward WDS related packets to the WDS server configured by option 66 in the DHCP. In addition, the configured NBP is boot\x64\wdsnbp.com
On some computers the procedure seems to be fine and they boot from WDS perfectly. But on most of other computers, when the boot image is loaded, an error is thrown by WDS saying: **WdsClient: There was a problem initializing WDS Mode.**
When I looked at the final lines of **windows\panther\setupact.log** the following error is written:

```
GetNetworkingInfo: Error retrieving network information. Error [0x80072743]
```

By the way, after a lot of investigation we've figured out that this problem usually occurs on computers with Reaktek NICs. So we tried to add Realtek drivers to the boot.wim image in the WDS console, but the problem still persists.
We also put our WDS server on the same subnet as workstations for test, but neither one of these solutions solved the case.